# importing csv in mysql database

Tags: java, mysql

I develop a GUI with Java in netbeans. I built a button which is used to import a csv file automatically in a database with this code:

```
JFileChooser fc=new JFileChooser(); 
fc.showOpenDialog(this);
File f=fc.getSelectedFile();
String path=f.getAbsolutePath();
try
{ 
    FileInputStream fin=new FileInputStream(f);
    int len=(int)f.length(); 
    java.sql.PreparedStatement ps1=con.prepareStatement("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\Users\\nabil.khedhri.stg\\Desktop\\TT.csv' INTO TABLE essai FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' LINES TERMINATED BY '\\\\r\\\\n' ");
    ps1.setBinaryStream(1, fin, len); 
    int status =ps1.executeUpdate();
    if(status > 0) 
    { 
        j1.setText("Successfully inserted in DB"); 
    }
    else
    { 
        j2.setText("Image not inserted!"); 
    } 
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

but no result.

Answer (score 0):

Any exception message on this? Check if demon mysqld running without option '--local-infile=0'. Check this" http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-data-local.html

Also, I would really think once again about such way on inserting records. Seems like user is able to load any file, it could be very dangerous from security point of view. Read about this in mysql manual. I would recommend to read csv file via some library line by line, validate it and load in table. Of course, if this is developer's tool and it will available only for couple developers for fast fix or load such way might be ok.